# Every file is corrupted in project

Tags: visual-studio, corrupt

Every file within my Visual Studio solution is corrupted.

I have to double-click each file within each project for the Visual Studio to recognize it and apply the appropriate file icon (i.e. xaml, cs, config).

I attempted to repair Visual Studio. However, the issue persists.

I have to double-click every file item in the solution each time I close and reopen the solution.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Look in the eventlog for anything suspicious

Comment: I sounds like the separate properties thingie has gotten mucked up.  Dunno how this is done in VS -- might be a registry thing, a plist, a SQL DB...

Comment: At Jgon: Isn't the question obvious? How do I resolve my corrupt solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the corruption by copying the solution from my SkyDrive back to my local hard drive.

I no longer receive any errors after opening the solution back on my local drive.